# How to pipe a Python's cmd class' input/output to another Python process?

Tags: python, linux, cmd, subprocess, piping

Currently, I'm running an experiment with [Mininet-Wifi](https://github.com/intrig-unicamp/mininet-wifi). It's CLI is Python's **Cmd** module and this is how I am able to get accurate information about the simulated network environment. The simulator is running as its own process as **sudo python** on Ubuntu 14.04 or greater.

The remote controller for this network is [POX](https://github.com/noxrepo/pox). This time, only a script is running; everything is automated with preset commands - no more human interaction. What I would like to do is: the POX process needs to inject commands into the Mininet's process and retrieve the results of the execution of that command. This is because POX's logic must constantly query the state of the network via Mininet to be able to make decisions. When a decision has been made, POX must again inject a command into the Mininet process to alter the state of the network.

ADDENDUM: Currently, I am only able to access the hosts that are spawned by Mininet when I run the **sudo python a_mininet_script**, thanks to the utility function called **m**. After spawning the hosts, Mininet enters its CLI function, which is what I want to communicate with but can't. This is Mininet's **m** function.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Attach to a Mininet host and run a command

if [ -z $1 ]; then
  echo "usage: $0 host cmd [args...]"
  exit 1
else
  host=$1
fi

pid=`ps ax | grep "mininet:$host$" | grep bash | grep -v mnexec | awk '{print $1};'`

if echo $pid | grep -q ' '; then
  echo "Error: found multiple mininet:$host processes"
  exit 2
fi

if [ "$pid" == "" ]; then
  echo "Could not find Mininet host $host"
  exit 3
fi

if [ -z $2 ]; then
  cmd='bash'
else
  shift
  cmd=$*
fi

cgroup=/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/$host
if [ -d "$cgroup" ]; then
  cg="-g $host"
fi

# Check whether host should be running in a chroot dir
rootdir="/var/run/mn/$host/root"
if [ -d $rootdir -a -x $rootdir/bin/bash ]; then
    cmd="'cd `pwd`; exec $cmd'"
    cmd="chroot $rootdir /bin/bash -c $cmd"
fi

cmd="exec sudo mnexec $cg -a $pid $cmd"
eval $cmd
```

For example, to access the terminal of *h1* from any terminal, not from the POX script, I'd call it thus:

```
sh m h1 ifconfig
```

But to call it from **subprocess**, it would be:

```
p = subprocess.Popen('echo my passwd | sudo -kS sh m h1 ifconfig', shell = True)
```

To repeat my question, I want to communicate with the CLI of the Mininet process *from the POX controller*, and not just the spawned hosts.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to realize the function something like netstat -oan | findstr 80 (this is on windows to find the port 80), this is the pipeline command to pass the output of netstat -oan to the command findstr.

Then the python code is something like:

```
import subprocess

p1 = subprocess.Popen('netstat -oan', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
p2 = subprocess.Popen('findstr 80', stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
pipeline_output = p2.communicate()[0]
print pipeline_output
```

Then, the p1 process output will be passed to p2 process, FYI.